# protractor getText() returns empty result

Tags: protractor, gettext

I have some list that gets filled with rows by ajax call,
above it I have an itemCount span - to show how many rows we have.
After the table is filled by rows, the itemCount span value is updated.
what I try to do is to copy this itemCount value, to add a new item to 
the list and then to test that the new itemCount value is bigger by 1 
than the old one.
The problem, I think, is that when I take the first value from the itemCount
span, it is still empty.
I tried to add browser.waitForAngular();, etc, but the value is still empty:

```
element(by.id('itemsCount')).getText().then(function(text) {
    console.log('**********' + text);
});
```

what I see is just: '**********'

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 1):

you could try using the [expected conditions](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/expectedConditions.js) like this.

```
var itemsCount    = element(by.id('itemsCount'));
var blank         = EC.textToBePresentInElementValue(itemsCount, '');
var itemsNotEmpty = EC.not(blank);

browser.wait(itemsNotEmpty, 5000, "✗ Failed to wait for the item count load").then(function() {
    itemsCount.getText().then(function(text) {
        console.log('**********' + text);
    });
});
```

Basically wait till the itemsCount isn't blank anymore then get it's text.

Answer (score 0):

There is some different between getText() and getAttribute(), depending on what sort of field it is. Can you try getAttribute and see if it grabs the text?